# Camel CXF JMS Connection issue

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to connect Weblogic JMS Topic through Camel CXF Consumer Client. But, it is giving the following error.

This issue might be because of jars incompatibility.

But, I am not sure which jar version of spring-jms is causing this issue?

I am using

camel version: 2.11.3
spring-jms-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Problem deserializing error response; nested exception is: 
      java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.jms.JMSException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8951994251593378324, local class serialVersionUID = 2368476267211489441
      at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
      at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:703)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receive(JmsTemplate.java:681)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receive(JmsTemplate.java:672)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsPollingConsumer.receive(JmsPollingConsumer.java:60)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsPollingConsumer.receive(JmsPollingConsumer.java:50)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.ConsumerCache.receive(ConsumerCache.java:105)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultConsumerTemplate.receive(DefaultConsumerTemplate.java:82)
      at examples.TestSimpleBuilder2.main(TestSimpleBuilder2.java:65)
Caused by: weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Problem deserializing error response; nested exception is: 
      java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.jms.JMSException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8951994251593378324, local class serialVersionUID = 2368476267211489441
      at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:116)
      at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:61)
      at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createDestination(JMSSession.java:3192)
      at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createTopic(JMSSession.java:2427)
      at weblogic.jms.client.WLSessionImpl.createTopic(WLSessionImpl.java:1123)
      at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveTopic(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:82)
      at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:63)
      at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.resolveDestinationName(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:100)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.access$2(JmsTemplate.java:1)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$10.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:705)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$10.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:1)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466)
      ... 8 more
Caused by: weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Problem deserializing error response; nested exception is: 
      java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.jms.JMSException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8951994251593378324, local class serialVersionUID = 2368476267211489441
      at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:345)
      at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:381)
      at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:59)
      ... 18 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Problem deserializing error response; nested exception is: 
      java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.jms.JMSException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8951994251593378324, local class serialVersionUID = 2368476267211489441
      at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.getThrowable(ResponseImpl.java:195)
      at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherProxy.unmarshalResponse(DispatcherProxy.java:263)
      at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherProxy.dispatchSyncTranFuture(DispatcherProxy.java:134)
      at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:334)
      ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.jms.JMSException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8951994251593378324, local class serialVersionUID = 2368476267211489441
      at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:604)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:498)
      at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
      at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1872)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
      at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:208)
      at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:599)
      at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.getThrowable(ResponseImpl.java:193)
      ... 23 more
```

Comment: Did you check if you have the Weblogic JMS client JARs in your classpath that matches the version of your Weblogic server?

Comment: Yes, all required jars are present in the classpath.

Comment: Any reference examples for Camel CXF Client server for Weblogic JMS would be really helpful?

Comment: What kind of message do you send from camel to Weblogic JMS? If you it's Java Object message, you need to make sure the object class version of the two sides is right.

Comment: Here, I am expecting a message from Weblogic JMS. I written a consumer  which points to weblogic JMS. It is able to connect to the JMS Topic on Weblogic but it is not returning the message while looking into message it shows this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the sender and receiver have different versions of the message classes.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.jms.JMSException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8951994251593378324, local class serialVersionUID = 2368476267211489441
```

Could you have regenerated the serialVersionUID and recompiled some of the code on either the producer or consumer?

One option to avoid this sort of problem is to serialise your data to XML or JSON rather than relying on Java's builtin serialisation support.

Comment: Yes, I checked that weblogic.jar is mismatched. Now, the issue is solved.

Comment: I had the exact same error but my root cause was different.  I had spaces/special characters in the selector value of a `SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint` which is apparently not good.  I was able to keep the spaces, but had to wrap the entire value in single quotes in order to do so.  As an added note I was using WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0.